# maldet command not found when installing LMD on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: malware

I am trying to install LMD linux malware Detect version 1.6.4 on Ubuntu. It shows that the installation was completed successfully; I could even open the conf.maldet for configuration options via terminal, when I try to run the LMD, it says "maldet command not found". I noticed on the installation guides/tutorials on previous versions that it will be automatically unpacked in usr/local/, mine says the same but when I go to my usr/local/  I do not see maldet as is expected. My maldetect-1.6.4 is installed in the home directory and it only contains a 'files' directory inside where all other directories are kept.

```
(base) mn@mn-MS-7C02:~$ -maldet --scan-all 
-maldet: command not found
(base) mn@mn-MS-7C02:~$ /home/mn/maldetect-1.6.4/files/maldet -u or maldet -d
Linux Malware Detect v1.6.4
            (C) 2002-2019, R-fx Networks <proj@rfxn.com>
            (C) 2019, Ryan MacDonald <ryan@rfxn.com>
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL v2

maldet(13231): {glob} $intcnf not found, aborting.
```

Any suggestion or help is very much appreciated.

Comment: There is a minus `-` in front of the command?!

Comment: I ran it with sudo maldet --scan-all  as well but it still says maldet command not found and intcnf not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command should be executed with superuser privilege, or enable `scan_user_access` in `conf.maldet`:

```
sudo maldet --scan-all
```

or:

```
sudo sed -i 's/scan_user_access="0"/scan_user_access="1"/' /usr/local/maldetect/conf.maldet
maldet --scan-all
```

**In your case**, to modify the configuration file:

```
sudo sed -i 's/scan_user_access="0"/scan_user_access="1"/' /home/mn/maldetect-1.6.4/files/conf.maldet
```

To run the command:

```
/home/mn/maldetect-1.6.4/files/maldet
```

You can create an alias, put the folowing line in your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias maldet='/home/mn/maldetect-1.6.4/files/maldet'
```

Then run:

```
exec bash
maldet
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but it still does not work. I assume it is because maldetect is not installed in usr/local/ and nothing I could do to install it there; I could not eve move it manually to usr/local/. Any suggestion?

Comment: @MaryamNasseri Install `mlocate` , run `updatedb` then `locate conf.maldet`

Comment: thank you very much for helping out. I did as you suggested and tried to run maldet again; it still says maldet command not found. I am sure I have installed it; I can view it (but it is not installed in usr/local/; it is automatically installed in home directory and I couldn't do anything to install it in usr/local/). mlocate also shows that it is installed in home directory.

Comment: @MaryamNasseri see my update, please.

Comment: Thanks for the update and for patiently answering my issues. I did as you said; added the maldet alias in the bashrc and saved it. when I run maldet, it now says it cannot find intconf so it aborts. When I check the maldet from the folder, this file is automatically installed in 'internals' under 'internals.conf'. I also ran the 'sudo maldet --scan-all' command but it still says 'maldet command not found'. You asked to run the 'exec bash' and then 'maldet'; when I run it it closes the terminal window by itself! I really don't know what's happening.

Comment: @MaryamNasseri Your are welcome, the terminal have a strange behaviour. Are you able to run commands with sudo? Try installing maldetect again it dosn't harm , and it should work for you just invok it from its path.

Comment: Thanks GAD3R for your suggestions. I had to remove v1.6.4 and install v1.6.5 from their github repo, in a different location and run it with `sudo maldet --scan-all` and it worked! I also noticed many users have complained about v.1.6.4 not finding the conf files. Thanks again.

Comment: @MaryamNasseri You are welcome again, glad that work for you, please if you found my answer useful don't forget to accept it.

Comment: @MaryamNasseri Also you have the possibility to answer your own question.